# How to use subquery combine group by DAY

Tags: mysql

Here is my table trans:

```
id //  user_id  //  money    //  date
 1        1001         20    2015-11-1
 2        1001         50    2015-11-1
 3        1001         50    2015-11-2
 4        1001         50    2015-11-3
 5        1002         10    2015-11-3
 6        1002         20    2015-11-1
 7        1002         70    2015-11-1
 8        1003         80    2015-11-2
 9        1003         10    2015-11-3
10        1003         20    2015-11-3
```

I wannt output like:

```
id //  user_id    // date
 1        1001     2015-11-1
 2        1001     2015-11-2
 3        1001     2015-11-3
 4        1002     2015-11-1
 5        1002     2015-11-3
 6        1003     2015-11-2
 7        1003     2015-11-3
```

Which means sum money group by  every day,every type and display by each id.
I tried GROUP BY DAY(date) like:

```
SELECT SUM(a.money), a.user_id FROM trans a GROUP BY DAY(date);
```

But it sum all the money by each day instead of by user_id.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can group by more than one column:

```
mysql> SELECT user_id, SUM(money), `date` FROM trans a GROUP BY user_id, date;
+---------+------------+------------+
| user_id | SUM(money) | date       |
+---------+------------+------------+
|    1001 |         70 | 2015-11-01 |
|    1001 |         50 | 2015-11-02 |
|    1001 |         50 | 2015-11-03 |
|    1002 |         90 | 2015-11-01 |
|    1002 |         10 | 2015-11-03 |
|    1003 |         80 | 2015-11-02 |
|    1003 |         30 | 2015-11-03 |
+---------+------------+------------+
7 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want a result row per user id, you should group by it:

```
SELECT   `user_id`, `day`, SUM(money)
FROM     `trans`
GROUP BY `user_id`, `day`
```